# Ensure atomicity when saving a model

Tags: python, django, database, concurrency, atomic

I am quite new to Django, and I am not sure how to manage concurrency.

I am building an application to reserve equipments.
I have a Reservation model with a ManytomanyField of Equipments.
 When I create a new reservation, I have to ensure that all the equipments are available.
The first version of my code doesn't care about concurrency:

```
def validate_reservation(keys, begin, end):

   eqpts = Equipment.objects.filter(pk__in=keys)
   if all(eqpt.is_available(begin, end) for eqpt in eqpts):
      res = Reservation(eqpts, begin, end)
      res.save()
      return True
   else:
      return False
```

The is_available method checks if there already are any reservation for the given dates:

```
  def is_available(self, begin, end):
        return not self.reservations.filter(begin__lte=end, end__gte=begin).exists()
```

The problem is that two users running this code may create Conflicting Reservations, if the first saves his reservation after the second checked the availability of the equipments.

I believe that I can solve the issue with transactions, so this I what I came up with:

```
def validate_reservation(keys, begin, end):

    with transaction.atomic():
       eqpts = Equipment.objects.select_for_update().filter(pk__in=keys)
       if all(eqpt.is_available(begin, end) for eqpt in eqpts):
          res = Reservation(eqpts, begin, end)
          res.save()
          return True
       else:
          return False
```

Does this have the intended behaviour ?
How can I know if the transaction failed and notify the user?

Is there a different and better way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this should work as long as you consistently use `select_for_update()` before modifying anything that could affect your availability check.

This code will not interfere with itself, since the `select_for_update()` will acquire row-level locks on the key rows at the beginning. But let's say you have another view that allows people to enter a reservation `pk` and change the beginning and ending times, or add a new piece of equipment. That could cause an inconsistency unless you explicitly do the same `select_for_update()` on the `Equipment` rows associated with that `Reservation`.

Note that your check is not very efficient. Anytime you're executing queries in a loop you should look for an alternative. In your case you should be able to find conflicts with a single query (that `JOINs` the tables):

```
has_conflict = Reservation.objects.filter(begin__lte=end,
                                          end__gte=begin,
                                          equipment__pk__in=keys).exists()
```

(Of course, you still have the concurrency problem so you'll still need to acquire an appropriate lock or use a different transaction isolation level.)

*How can I know if the transaction failed and notify the user?*

The transaction will not fail, it will just block until the locks have been released. You can use `select_for_update(nowait=True)` (on some databases) if you want the transaction to fail instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the better check !
My lock is still appropriate for your check, right ? Can you tell me more about the other transaction isolation level you mentionned ?

Comment: @Atn: You didn't mention your database, but the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/transaction-iso.html) offers a good description of transaction isolation levels. That said, I like your row locks idea better, and it would still work just as well with the above check.